# Erro no Zend Framework 3

Tags: php, zend-framework-3

Estou tentando abrir abrir a url localhost:8080/pessoa porém sempre apresenta um fatal error ( Uncaught Zend\Router\Exception\RuntimeException) que nao consigo interpretar direito.

Meus diretorios estao assim:

```
-config
 *pplication.config.php
 *development.config.php
 *development,config.php.dist
 *modules.config.php
-data
-module
  -Application
  -Pessoa
    -config
      *module.config.php
    -src
      -Controller
        *PessoaController.php
    *Module.php
    -test
    -view
      -pessoa
        -pessoa
             *index.phtml   
-public
-vendor
```

**Stack trace:**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Zend\Router\Exception\RuntimeException: Found
>   unbalanced brackets in
>   C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\Http\Segment.php:218
>   Stack trace: #0
>
> C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\Http\Segment.php(112):
>   Zend\Router\Http\Segment->parseRouteDefinition('/pessoa[/:actio...')#1
>   C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\Http\Segment.php(147):
>   Zend\Router\Http\Segment->__construct('/pessoa[/:actio...', Array,
>   Array) #2
>
> C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\RouteInvokableFactory.php(105):
>   Zend\Router\Http\Segment::factory(Array) #3
>
> C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(764):
>   Zend\Router\RouteInvokableFactory->__invoke(Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager),
>   'Zend\Router\Htt...', Array) #4
>
> C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(227):
>   Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceMan in
>
> C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php
>   on line 771

**Arquivos (Vou colocar apenas os que eu editei):**

**modules.config.php**

```
<?php
    return [
        'Zend\Router',
        'Zend\Validator',
        'Application',
        'Pessoa',
    ];
```

**module.config.php**

```
<?php 

namespace Pessoa; 
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory; 


return [
    'router'  => [ 
        'routes' => [
            'pessoa' => [
                'type' =>\Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
                'options' => [
                    'route' => '/pessoa[/:action[/:id]',
                    'constraints' => [
                        'action' => '[a-ZA-Z][a-ZA-Z0-9_-]*', 
                        'id' => '[0-9]+', 

                    ],
                    'defaults' => [
                        'controller' => Controller\PessoaController::class, 
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ], 
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Controller\PessoaController::class => InvokableFactory::class, 
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [ 
        'template_path_stack' => [ 
            'pessoa' => __DIR__. '/../view', 
        ],
    ],
];
```

**PessoaController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Pessoa\Controller;
use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


class PessoaController extends AbstractActionController 
{

    public function indexAction() 
    {
        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

**Module.php**

```
<?php

namespace Pessoa;
use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{ 

    public function getConfig() 
    {
        return include __DIR__."/../config/module.config.php";
    }
}
```

**index.phtml**

```
<?php
    $var = "Funciona!!!!!";
?>
<h1>Minha view do controller pessoa no modulo Pessoa</h1> 
<p><?= $var ?></p>
```

Comment: Não conheço o framework, mas me parece que está faltando um `]` na linha `'route' => '/pessoa[/:action[/:id]',` em `module.config.php`

Comment: Obg pela ajuda. Coloquei o colchete que faltava. Mas ainda ta dando erro, so que outro ->  Compilation failed: range out of order in character class at offset 26 in C:\Users\Igor\Desktop\ProjetoZF2\vendor\zendframework\zend-router\src\Http\Segment.php on line 387

Answer (score -2):

```
        'pessoa' => [
            'type' =>\Zend\Router\Http\Segment::class,
            'options' => [
                'route' => '/pessoa[/:action[/:id]]',
                'constraints' => [
                    'action' => '[a-ZA-Z][a-ZA-Z0-9_-]*', 
                    'id' => '[0-9]+', 

                ],
                'defaults' => [
                    'controller' => Controller\PessoaController::class, 
                    'action' => 'index',
                ],
            ],
        ],
```

Comment: Poderia explicar o que é esse código e por que ele responderia a pergunta?

Comment: Simples, é apenas uma questão de sintaxe, o trecho de código do seu código que eu destaquei esta com um erro de sintaxe.

Comment: Você escreveu: 'route' => '/pessoa[/:action[/:id]',
O correto é: 'route' => '/pessoa[/:action[/:id]]',

Comment: Mesmo que o código não seja meu, Isso poderia estar descrito na resposta, pois da forma atual não fica claro como você resolveu.

Comment: Desculpe minha ignorância, sou novato.

Comment: Matheus, logo abaixo da sua resposta existe a opção "Editar", use-a para completar a sua resposta com a explicação do que fez. Como é novo no site, recomendo que faça o [tour] e acesse a [help] para mais informações.